# Boolean in a constructor only setting to true

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

I'm fairly new to java coding and I basically am creating a Bear class that is supposed to either choose color white or black based on the user input. 
If it is a polar bear it's supposed to choose white, and if it's a black bear it's supposed to choose black.

This is the code I have so far:

```
//constructor
public Bear(boolean polar) {
   this.polar = polar;
}

public Color getColor() {
   if (polar == true) {
      return Color.WHITE;
   } else {
      return Color.BLACK;
   }
}
```

The argument being passed is through a testing class which is this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Critter makeCritter(Class critter) throws Exception {
        Constructor c = critter.getConstructors()[0];
        if (critter.toString().equals("class Bear")) {
            // flip a coin
            boolean b = Math.random() < 0.5;
            return (Critter) c.newInstance(new Object[] {b});
        } else {
            return (Critter) c.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

But when I run my code, it only returns White. How could I fix my code so it returns black or white depending on if the polar boolean is true or false?

Comment: Have you instantiated your class with `false` argument? like `new Bear(false)` ?

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the constructor when you instantiate the Bear?

Comment: I've added additional info in the edit

Comment: what is returned from `Bear(polar)` will be used to check againt the `polar` condition in the `getColor()` maybe consider a more generic name as the attribute member in `Bear()` so as to show both colors represented, and like the comments suggested is that it needs to be instantiated for the black bear case as well.

Comment: As a note, don't use `==` to compare booleans; just say `if (polar)` (or `return polar ? WHITE : BLACK;`).

Comment: @FishingCode Could you explain that again? How could I show both colors being represented and instantiate for the black bear case?

Comment: something like this possibly, `getColor = Bear(false)` for either color cases evaluate `true` and `false` using separate instantiated cases. although there may need to be some extra modifying off the function.

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/oY6Y1o - There could be an issue else-where in your code.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Oh I just ran it again, and it works this time. IDK why it didn't work when I ran it before. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the answer from @agprogramming, that could help clarify the issue you may have had. Please let us know if it did by marking it as accepted answer, or commenting whether it was the solution or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check the below comparison in the test code through debug whether control is going in the if condition.

```
if (critter.toString().equals("class Bear"))
```

Here it might be looking for package name along with class name for comparison like:

```
if (critter.toString().equals("class packageName.Bear"))
```

Comment: This is a good point - it could be improved further by using the class reference itself - `critter.equals(Bear.class)`. If the class packages are refactored, a string reference wouldn't automatically be updated by the IDE.